# How to switch roles when your expertise is in a certain field

Tags: career-switch

I am a developer with expertise in Qt GUIs. I was assigned to it when I was a fresher in a different company. But overtime I've started to hate working on the technology.

The reason simply being that I get constant changes which are never documented (despite my effort). The timelines are not moved. When pointed out, I am told that apparently this was part of the original estimate.
Apart from the above mentioned, GUI is simply speaking given the least priority and importance while it is also the first thing the user sees.

Basically, over the 2 companies I've worked with, the teams are understaffed while expectations are high. Last but not the least, the projects are always ancient with zero documentation and large number of permutations for testing (which are unknown to everyone as GUI people don't stay). One requirement generally means a hundred more changes (the requirement to create a building in 3D also entails the ability to delete it for instance).

Also, I have a personal amazement for back-end work. I like to be the guy who creates all kinds of data structures and what not.

The problem is that my CV contains different ways for using Qt GUI. This prevents me for applying for a good C/C++ coder job (The interviewers basically state that I don't have any experience with C/C++. No technical questions asked). My current company needs more Qt people (no one is willing to learn it and the freshers whom I've trained somehow magically end up getting a better paying job in Qt at a different firm) so, they won't let me switch no matter what.

Edit: Forgot to mention, I've never seen a position for a senior developer in the field in my area.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to search for more junior roles and then emphasise your knowledge in the interview stage stating that you would like to broaden your skill-set by moving into a different field.

A junior role may not pay as well as what you're earning now, but at least it gets your experience down on paper and you have the option to move upward within the company that you're moving into.  Or not, as the case may be (but at least you have experience with this skill on your resume).

Basically, you might have to demote on a temporary basis yourself in order to cross to another technology.  It's going to be easier to do that than to get a "good" job by blagging your way in without having some experience to demonstrate your skills.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is gain experience in the role you want to move into.  If there are opportunities within your company to take on responsibilities that deal with the technologies, do so.

Barring that, you also have the option of doing freelance work, volunteering for charities, or participating in collaborative and/or open source projects.

Then, your options open up.  Companies may or may not wish to risk taking you on in a senior role even after that, but they're not going to look at you at all if you cannot demonstrate proficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with other answers that volunteering for different kinds of work within your own team or company is a good first step.

It's quite a big jump you want to make, but another way you can try to make this change is to focus on your experience with the kind of application rather than the programming language. If you've spent a lot of time working on a product in a certain domain (for example CRM or collaboration) or with a certain application architecture (such as microservices or client-server), you may be able to apply to companies making similar software and sell your domain knowledge and expertise with that kind of application rather than with Qt GUIs.

Whatever approach you take you will probably need to accept a step down at the same time as others have suggested.